# Linetype based on list

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got a list and some data

```
l <- c('b', 'a')
frame <- data.frame(series = rep(c('a', 'b'), 6), x = c(1:12), y = c(1:12))
```

and I'd like to plot a smoothed line via

```
ggplot(frame, data) + geom_smooth(linetype=series)
```

But I need the `linetype` based on the list `l`, the first element in the list `l` should be
normal, the second element of the list dotted. I tried

```
ggplot(frame, data) + geom_smooth() + scale_linetype_manual("", values=series, breaks=l)
```

But that doesn't apply any linetype.

Comment: Note your definition of `frame` should have `=` instead of `<-` within the `data.frame` call. Also, your example doesn't appear to work; `ggplot(frame,data)+geom_smooth()` complains about `data` not being wrapped into `aes`; and you need to specify both `x` and `y` within `aes`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You example data is a little odd, in that you have a grouping variable (series) and one numerical column (data), but it sounds like you want to plot two variables. Here's some possibly more relavent example data:

```
frame <- data.frame(series = rep(c('a','b'),6),x = runif(12),y = runif(12))
```

Note the use of `=` rather than `<-`. Had you noticed that the column names of your data frame were unspeakably ugly? ;) Also note that I didn't use the word `data`, as that can get confusing as it is used as a function, and oftentimes an argument.

Then you could plot two lines like this:

```
ggplot(frame,aes(x = x,y = y)) + 
    geom_line(aes(linetype = series,group = series))
```

Or two smoothed lines like this (with copious warnings thrown due to the small size of the data):

```
ggplot(frame,aes(x = x,y = y)) + 
    geom_smooth(aes(linetype = series,group = series))
```

The key here is that you pass `ggplot` a data frame (`frame`) and then *map variables to aesthetics* using the `aes()` function. In this case, we've mapped the x,y values to our x,y variables, and mapped linetype to series. But we have to tell ggplot how to group the data, hence the use of the group aesthetic.

Aesthetics can be mapped in `ggplot` in which case they carry forward to subsequent geoms, or they can be mapped in only the geom in which they are used.

Finally, to specify which line types to use, you were correct in trying `scale_linetype_manual`:

```
+ scale_linetype_manual(values = 2:3)
```

where you pass to the `values` argument the linetypes you want used. in the scale. You can also pass a named vector to `values`, so specify which levels get which line types:

```
+ scale_linetype_manual(values = c('a' = 2,'b' = 3))
```

Comment: And how can I tell `ggplot` which linetype to use for which value of the `series`?

Comment: That's the part where you were right -- use `scale_linetype_manual`.

Comment: I generate 4 plots from this, with different series names (which do not correspond alphabetically), so I've got `current` and `prev` which are in the list `l`, and I'd like to assign linetypes according to `l`.

Comment: @Tass I don't understand. What's your question?

Comment: How do I make a mapping as in `frame$series == "a" #=> straight line` and `frame$series == "b" #=> dotted line`?

Comment: @Tass Exactly as I demonstrated, using `scale_linetype_manual`. Have you experimented with changing the ordering of the values passed to `values`? Have you investigated `?par` -> `lty` to read about line type specifications?

Comment: Changing the order works in some cases, in some others of the 4, it doesn't. So second one. Could you give me a link? It's not that easy to google...

Comment: @Tass I can't reproduce the behavior you describe with `scale_linetype_manual`. Might be best as a separate question. If you type `?par` are the console in R you'll get the help page for a whole slew of graphical parameters, including `lty` which will describe how to specify line types.

Comment: That was the question in the first place.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9611/discussion-between-joran-and-tass)